# Render a directive with two datasources

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

My problem is a bit complex, so i will try to explain it as detailed as possible.

I have a directive in a SPA that render their components based on a JSON data that i'm getting from an API. Based on the elements and their types (the JSON is an array of different objects) i'm rendering every object in an specific directive:

- Objects Type 1: Renders in a Directive Type 1.
- Objects Type 2: Renders in a Directive Type 2.
- Objects Type 3: Renders in a Directive Type 3.

Directives Type 1-2-3 are contained in the parent directive and every directive has different controls (select, checkbox). This is a very simple Sketch:

[image: Parent Directive and Directives Type 1-2-3]

And the "sub-directives":

[image: Sub-directive]

I'm rendering my elements as follows (`Container directive`):

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elementList | customFilter:itemsType1">
  <div class="line"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <directivetype1 itemdata="element" modeldata="data"></directivetype1>
  </div>
</div>

<div ng-repeat="element in elementList | customFilter:itemsType2">
  <div class="line"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <directivetype2 itemdata="element" modeldata="data"></directivetype2>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

And this is the `Directive 1` code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox"/>{{itemdata.metadata.description}}</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
      <label>Option</label>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="" ng-options="list.id as list.label for list in item.optionData"></select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***My problem goes when i try to attach the model to every element rendered, because of:***

1. The model data comes from another API, in another structure.
2. I'm iterating the list of controls with ng-repeat, but, when i pass the model data to the sub-directive i'm passing all the possible data (as Array) and i'm not being capable of filter and know what object in that array belongs to an specific view element.

The data has the following structure:

**View data:**

```
[
    {
        "elementA": {
            "metadata": {
                "id": "001",
                "subId": "016",
                "description": "Element 1"
            },
            "optionData": [
                {
                    "id": "5",
                    "label": "Option 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6",
                    "label": "Option 2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7",
                    "label": "Option 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "elementB": {
            "metadata": {
                "id": "002",
                "subId": "024",
                "description": "Element 2"
            },
            "optionData": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "label": "Option 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "label": "Option 2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3",
                    "label": "Option 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

**Model data:**

```
[
    {
        "metadata": {
            "id": "002",
            "subId": "024",
            "description": "Element 2",
            "selected": "1"
        },
        ...(Some other data belonging to the model)
    },
    {
        "metadata": {
            "id": "001",
            "subId": "016",
            "description": "Element 1",
            "selected": "5"
        },
        ...(Some other data belonging to the model)
    },
    ...
]
```

As you can see, the only way to correlate both models is with `id` and `subId` Fields in the `metadata` object (because the `metadata` itself can vary having more or less fields).

**QUESTION**

*How can i filter my model object, based on the view object? My goal is to get the model object that correlates to the view object and pass it to the sub-directive for setting it as the model of the control that i'm rendering at that point.*

**EDIT**:

As cmw pointed out, i've coded a function to correlate every model object with their respective view object, but that object is not reflected in the directive scope. `itemdata` and `modeldata` are passed to the directive using a bi-directional scope ('='). I think (but i'm not entirely sure) that, when i pass a function to `modeldata` the directive is not being capable of setting the returned object. The solution that i've coded based on the cmw answer is as follows:

Directive:

```
<directivetype1 itemdata="element" modeldata="getModelObject(data)"></directivetype1>
```

JS (coded in the Ctrl of the parent):

```
$scope.getModelObject = function(element){
  var id = typeof element.metadata === 'undefined' ? null : element.metadata.id;
  var subid = typeof element.metadata === 'undefined' ? null : element.metadata.subid;
  var modelElement = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i += 1){
    element = $scope.data[i];
    if (modelElement.metadata.id === id && modelElement.metadata.subid === id) return element;
  }

  return null;
};
```

But when i try to work in the directive with `modeldata` i see "null" in FF/Chrome Console.

Any guideline to know what's happening?

Thanks.

**EDIT 2:**

I've added a version of my code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/xjp1l3PuWczdqYf5LP8q?p=preview. Sadly, in that Plunkr it works as expected but my code does not (i'm expecting to see the output of `<h1>{{modeldata}}</h1>`). I'm comparing the two versions to see any difference (note that i've included the same AngularJS version that i'm using in my project).

Comment: Maybe you can use a function to get the object you want with the object you have inside your `ng-repeat`, like `itemdata="getModelObject(element)"`

Comment: @Arg0n I've tried, as cmw suggested. Please see my edit.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle for this?

Comment: @Arg0n See the Edit 2

Comment: As you are saying, since it's working in the Plunkr, then something else must be the problem.

Comment: @Arg0n Yes, i'm trying to figure it out what's the real problem. I'll provide further updates. Thank you

Comment: @Arg0n I've found the problematic line (i haven't included it in the code). What kind of effect does this line have on the code: `$scope.viewdata = $scope.viewdata[Object.keys($scope.viewdata)[0]];`? (I have updated the Plunkr with that line)

Comment: I changed it.. I removed the controller and modified the template for the directive. See this updated Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/MUVHCrrVKUpYeYNhe2IO?p=preview (The line set `viewdata` to `viewdata.metadata`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've pointed out, I believe the key is simply to make use of the `id` and `subId` properties on the `meta` object.

Something like this would probably work...

```
<div ng-repeat="element in elementList | customFilter:itemsType1">
  <div class="line"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <directivetype1 itemdata="element" modeldata="modelDataFor(element)">
    </directivetype1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your controller, define a function like the following...

```
$scope.modelDataFor = function (element) {
  var id    = element.meta.id,
      subId = element.meta.subId,
      curr;

  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i += 1) {
    curr = $scope.data[i];
    if (curr.meta.id === id && curr.meta.subId === subId) {
      return curr;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

This seems like the most natural place to pluck out the relative data model object to pass into your nested directives.

Comment: I have a two-way binding between the parent and the child. Applying this function does bind any change that i make in the model to the original object?

Comment: I've marked this as the answer of my problem. I figured it out that i have another that it's in a different scope. Thank you!